# $_FILES not working with JS "Undefined array key"

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code which working perfectly on its own; however when JS get involved the mess starts.

HTML code is about drag and drop images

PHP code is to upload the selected image to the server

JS code is to add some taste to the page itself, like showing some guiding text and previewing the selected image before uploading.

Here's the HTML CODE

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="maincont">
         <h3>Upload your Card</h3>
             <div class="drag-area">
                 <div class="icon">
                     <i class="fas fa-images"></i>
                 </div>
                      <span class="header">Drag & Drop</span>
                      <span class="header">or <span class="button">browse</span></span>
                      <input type="file" name="file" hidden>
                      <span class="support">Supports JEPG, JPG, PNG</span>
             </div>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" >Upload Card</button>    
      </div>
</form>
```

The PHP CODE

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    // print_r($file);
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
        if ($fileSize <  50000)   {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploadsx/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            header("Location: final.php?Nice");
        }else {
            echo "Your file is too big!";  
        }  
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}
```

and here's the JS code

```
const dragArea = document.querySelector('.drag-area');
const dragtext = document.querySelector('.header');

let button = document.querySelector('.button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');

let file;

button.onclick = () => {
    input.click();
};

// when browse
input.addEventListener('change', function () {
    file = this.files[0];
    dragArea.classList.add('active');
    displayFile()

})

//When file is inside the drag area
dragArea.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dragtext.textContent = 'Release to upload';
    dragArea.classList.add('active');
    // console.log('File is inside the drag area')
})

// when file leaves the drag area
dragArea.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
    dragtext.textContent = 'Drag & Drop';
    dragArea.classList.remove('active');
    // console.log('File left the drag area')
})

// When the file is droped in the drag area
dragArea.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    // console.log(file);
    displayFile()
})

function displayFile() {
    let fileType = file.type;
    // console.log(fileType);

    let validExtentions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];

    if(validExtentions.includes(fileType)) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = () => {
            let fileURL = fileReader.result;
            //  console.log(fileURL);
            let imgTag = `<img src="${fileURL}" alt="">`;
            dragArea.innerHTML = imgTag;
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        alert('This file is not an image');
        dragArea.classList.remove('active');
    }
        // console.log('The file is droped in drag area');
}
```

Error Code

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 5

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 7

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 7

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 8

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 8

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 9

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 9
You cannot upload files of this type!

Comment: What is the undefined array key in the error message?

Comment: Why do you keep using `$_FILES['file']` after you defined `$file = $_FILES['file']`? Isn't the whole point of that so you don't have to repeat that, e.g. `$file['name']`

Comment: @Barmar 
here's the error code

`Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 5

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "file" in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in L:\Xampp\htdocs\f\upload.php on line 6`

and same error with every line have word "File"

Comment: That should be in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: That error is referening `$_FILES`, not `$_POST` like you say in the question title.

Comment: None of your JavaScript adds the dropped file to the `input` value.

Comment: Really sorry about the messy post, I was to frustrated after 10hrs of trying. regarding your suggestion to be honest I don't know how to do it but I'll search about it.

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/ shows how to do it with AJAX instead of a `<form>`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it right now and I'll come back with the update.